# Is it possible to run Activity and Fragment simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am looking for a way to run activity and fragment at the same time where activity will show two buttons to transition from one activity to the other whereas fragment will show live camera view in the background.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are the part of activity. So it's obvious that activity and fragment run simultaneously run. Fragment does not have it's own context. After read your question I think you want that you can change the fragments but buttom buttom are place there for all fragment. You can do this like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

add and replace your fragment on framelayout so each fragment have the button at bottom which is the part of activity.

Comment: Actually i hava one xml layout file which contain background Imageview and two buttons on top of that background  okay, then what i want to achieve is that i want to replace that background with the live view of my Camera.